# Price range slider for my website

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wish to have a slider similar to they use.

http://www.koovs.com/apple-ipod

Can anyone suggest how a slider can be customized to that form or an already existing plugin if any.

Thanks !

Comment: Googling "jquery range slider" would have given you the same result... [Try it](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&pq=jquery%20slider&cp=8&gs_id=g&xhr=t&q=jquery+range+slider&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jquery+rslider&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bcdad2636ddf28f5&biw=1280&bih=709&ix=seb&ion=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the range slider through the standard jQuery UI library. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Answer (score 2):

Try jquery and jquery-ui

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Answer (score 1):

jslider i like this one was looking into the same thing a while back

http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/