# jQuery price slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I need a simple jQuery price slider in my site. From a £0 to £1000 amount.

Say the browser sets the slider to £100 (for example), I then need a buy now button that transfers to Paypal with the amount the slider is set to!

I've not got a lot of experience with javascript any idea's?

Thanks in advance,

Neal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Price range slider for my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855647/price-range-slider-for-my-website)

Comment: (Java has nothing to do with Javascript); simple slider http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: Try google "jQuery price slider" and press "I feel lucky"

Comment: @Scott: The one you've proposed as a duplicate is a range slider. He's after a one-handle slider from 0 to 1000...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - It's still the jQuery UI slider.  Range is just one dimension of the slider object.

Answer (score 3):

Use the jQuery UI slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

In the change event of the slider you can then update the value of the hidden form field containing the money amount.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's entire question.

Comment: @Scott: Doesn't, right. But he'll have to figure out PayPal by reading integration documentation. It's not on us to deliver the cake for them to eat...

Comment: Initially I didn't mention the change event

Answer (score 0):

I would consider giving the HTML 5 slider a look into. Should be on the lines you are looking for.

here is a quick tutorial:

http://webhole.net/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/

Comment: Not even supported in the currently stable firefox.